# Cleaning text data for Neural Machine translation

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I am cleaning my data to  get pairs of text for converting from language X to Y for machine translation

```
    [['\ufeffMensahe di Pasco di Gobernador di Aruba 2019',
  'Governor’s Christmas speech 2019'],
 ['Gobernador di Aruba Sr. Alfonso Boekhoudt a duna su mensahe di Pasco riba 24 december ultimo',
  'On Christams eve, December 24, the Governor of Aruba Mr. Alfonso Boekhoudt gave his traditional Christmas speech'],
 ['Por a wak e discurso di Pasco di Gobernador via e canalnan di television local',
  "The governor's Christmas speech was shown at the local television stations"],......
```

Above is the data that goes in the following piece of code:

```
def clean_pairs(lines):
cleaned = list()
for pair in lines:
    clean_pair = list()
    for line in pair:
        # normalize unicode characters
        line = normalize('NFD', line).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        line = line.decode('UTF-8')
        # tokenize on white space
        line = line.split()
       .
       .
       .
       .
    clean_pair.append(' '.join(line))
cleaned.append(clean_pair)


for i in range(10):
    print('[%s]->[%s]' % (cleaned[i,0], cleaned[i,1]))
```

I should get the output as :

```
[hi]->[hallo]
[hi]->[gru gott]
[run]->[lauf]
[wow]->[potzdonner]
[wow]->[donnerwetter]
```

however, I get the below error:

---

> IndexError
> Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 49
> 50 for i in range(10):
> ---> 51     print('[%s]->[%s]' % (clean_pairs[i,0], clean_pairs[i,1]))
>
> IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2
> were indexed

Can someone help me with whats going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Clearly the list is 1-dimensional. Can you print the whole list raw? Maybe try `clean_pairs[i][0]` or see if it's a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure is a list of lists. In Python you index them like this:

```
clean[i][0] #  not like clean[i,0]
```